# Выделение жирным текста в ячейке Google Sheets

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

В реализацию попала такая задача: чтобы различать, откуда попали данные в таблицу, их необходимо выделить.

Есть ли способы установки свойств текста в *Google Sheets API*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так

```
// формат
$format = [
    'backgroundColor' => [
        'red' => 0.1,
        'green' => 0.1,
        'blue' => 0.1,
        'alpha' => 1,
    ],
    'textFormat' => [
      'bold' => true
    ]
];



// получить sheetId с номером 0
$sheetId = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);
$sheetId = $sheetId->sheets[0]->properties->sheetId;

// ячейка
$myRange = [
    'sheetId' => $sheetId, // 
    'startRowIndex' => 1,
    'endRowIndex' => 1,
    'endColumnIndex' => 2,
];

// Запрос
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'repeatCell' => [
            'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor, userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold',
            'range' => $myRange,
            'cell' => [
                'userEnteredFormat' => $format,
            ],
        ],
    ])
];

$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```